# what is the difference between a forward slash and a backward slash?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In group/ring theory, what does is the difference between forward slash and a backwards slash?
for example, I am studying quotient theory and they use it.
H $ \subseteq $ G, then what is the difference between H/G and H\G?

Answer (score 2):

The forward and backward slash are used to denote which coset we are considering (left or right, respectively)

Comment: that would make great sense thank you.